# Can't create new roles using mosquitto dynamic security Connection error: Not authorized

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mqtt, file-permissions, mosquitto

The permissions on my dynamic-security.json file is the following:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 mosquitto mosquitto 1247 Mar  6 06:51 dynamic-security.json
```

After trying to add a new role:

```
mosquitto_ctrl -u myadmin -P admin333 dynsec createRole firstRole
```

Also tried:

```
sudo mosquitto_ctrl -u myadmin -P <mypassword> dynsec createRole firstRole
```

I also tried it with all permissions allowed, and with the owner being the root. It all gave me the same error.

```
Connection error: Not authorized
```

The dynamic-security.json file was generated with:

```
sudo mosquitto_ctrl dynsec init /var/lib/mosquitto/dynamic-security.json myadmin
```

And this is the contents of the mosquitto.conf file:

```
persistence true
persistence_location /etc/mosquitto/data
user mosquitto
listener 1883
per_listener_settings false
allow_anonymous false 
password_file /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/credentials
log_dest file /etc/mosquitto/log/mosquitto.log
log_dest stdout
plugin /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mosquitto_dynamic_security.so
plugin_opt_config_file /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dynamic-security.json
```

Comment: This will not be a file permission problem, it will be the admin username/password either being wrong or a problem with plugin setup

Comment: Please do not try and add details in comments, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75647942/edit) the original question, also include details about how you generated the original dynamic-security.json file.

Comment: I also suggest you put the `dynamic-security.json` file in `/etc/mosquitto` not `/usr/lib`

Comment: I'll change the location and see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the plugin_opt_config_file location in the mosquitto.conf file:

```
plugin_opt_config_file /etc/mosquitto/dynamic-security.json
```

I have also removed the old dynamic-security.json file and created a new one in the new location using:

```
sudo mosquitto_ctrl dynsec init /etc/mosquitto/dynamic-security.json myadmin
```

And then most importantly, i restarted the mosquitto.service. Now it works fine!